# Joining tables with Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, join, laravel, laravel-4

I have a few models that are joined by a pivot table.

```
Models:
  Project
  BU
  Level        -- An ID showing how project affects a BU

Tables:
  projects
  bus
  levels
  project_bu   -- Pivot table joining all 3 models above
    id
    project_id
    bu_id
    level_id
```

The pivot join is working fine and pulling what is expected. I'm using the following code in my model:

```
public function bus() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('BU')->join('levels', 'level_id', '=', 'levels.id')->select('levels.level as level', 'levels.id as level_id');
}
```

However, I was curious, is it possible to do a join or something on the original BU table, so that I get all values of the BU, even if the value isn't present? So, if I have 5 BUs, but only 2 of them have values in the pivot table, 5 would still be returned from the model with either null or 0 as the level value.

Comment: You have to put `5` entries in the `pivot` tables for to get `5` related models.

Comment: I figured that could be a possibility, however when I add a new BU down the road, then that pivot table is out of date unless I go back and re-add a null/0 for each project in that pivot table.

Comment: Just manually join to any tables you want. You can use the Query Builder methods with eloquent, e.g. YourModel::join()->join()->etc.